# query to get count, subtotal and total over a date range

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

Say I have objects with a `created_at` attribute.  I would like to have
a query that will result in the counts of created objects on a given date
(`count_`), **subtotal** of objects up to that date (`sub`), and the full
total of all objects (`total_`):

```
  date      | count_ |   sub | total_
------------+--------+-------+-------
 2018-10-08 |      1 |     1 |    15
 2018-10-11 |      2 |     3 |    15
 2018-10-15 |      3 |     6 |    15
 2018-10-23 |      4 |    10 |    15
 2018-10-24 |      5 |    15 |    15
```

I managed to get `count_` and `total_`:

```
Obj.objects.annotate(
    date=Trunc('created_at', 'day', output_field=DateField())
).values(
    'date'
).annotate(
    count_=Window(expression=Count('id'), partition_by=[F('date')]),
    total_=Window(expression=Count('id'))
).distinct()
```

generating this `SQL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('day', "obj_obj"."created_at") AS "date",
       COUNT("obj_obj"."id") OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('day', "obj_obj"."created_at")) AS "count_",
       COUNT("obj_obj"."id") OVER () AS "total_"
  FROM "obj_obj"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=721a5f50ffc8c5ccc9396fd8903b0c8e)

You need the [cumulative window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). This can be achieved by adding an `ORDER BY` clause. If this exists, the `COUNT()` will be cumulative as you expect. If it doesn't exist, the COUNT will be taken over the whole frame.

```
count(created_at) OVER (ORDER BY created_at) as subtotal
```

The query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    created_at,
    count(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY created_at) as count_,
    count(created_at) OVER (ORDER BY created_at) as subtotal_,
    count(created_at) OVER () as total_
FROM
    dates
```

So although I am not really into Django I believe you need a line like:

```
subtotal_=Window(expression=Count('id'), order_by=[F('date')]),
```